# Creating a dictionary of edges given dictionary of nodes in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nodes, edges

I have a dictionary of nodes with this format: `{string: list, string: list, ...}`. I need to make edges between two keys that share an element in their value lists. Basically I want to make a table with three columns: `shared element, key 1, key 2`.

This is what I have:

```
edges = []

for v in nodesDict.list():
    for x in v:
      shared_element = x
      key1 = k
      edges.append(shared_element + ',' + key1)
```

So that makes tuples with each value element paired with its key, right? I'm just not sure now how to match the pairs with shared values to each other and make the table.

Thanks! Also, if anyone has a more efficient way of doing this instead of checking each to the other, that would be great too.

Comment: Hey, if you like one of the answers make sure you accept it!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Using a set instead of a tuple is better because an edge is an unordered collection of unique elements, aka a set.

I think it might be smart, depending on the final purpose of the edge/node dicts, to have the edge `dict` storing the nodes as a `set`:

```
edge: (node1, node2)
```

So you have an already formed `dict` of `node:[edges]`. I would create the new dict like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

edgeDict = defaultdict(set) 
for node in nodesDict.keys():
    for edge in nodesDict[node]:
        edgeDict[edge].add(node)
```

With the `defaultdict`, you maintain the same functionality that you would have with a `dict`, only when you call the `__getitem__()` method on a nonexistant item, it will add that item into the `dict`.

You can also leverage this new dict to create a list of tuples in the form of `(edge, node1, node2)` with a one-liner list comp:

```
[tuple(edge) + tuple(nodes) for edge, nodes in edgeDict.items()]
```

---

At the same time, there are some third party modules that can clean up any graph business you have to take care of. [NetworkX](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/tutorial/tutorial.html) is a popular module.

Comment: I second @Al.Sal re [NetworkX](http://networkx.github.io/), which is a very comprehensive library. I would also highly recommend [iGraph](http://igraph.org/python/).

Answer (score 0):

First, an example:

```
nodesDict = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [3, 4], 'C': [1, 4, 5]}
```

From which we can deduce the expected result:

```
# [(1, 'A', 'C'), (3, 'A', 'B'), (4, 'A', 'B'), (4, 'A', 'C'), (4, 'B', 'C')]
```

To get that, the easier is to start by reversing the dict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

revDict = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in nodesDict.items():
    for item in v:
        revDict[item].append(k)
```

Now, you have the reversed the dict, you can simply iterate on it, combine the elements, and voila:

```
from itertools import combinations
edges = []
for k, v in revDict.items():
    if len(v) > 1:
        for values in combinations(v, 2):
            edges.append((k,) + values)

print edges

# [(1, 'A', 'C'), (3, 'A', 'B'), (4, 'A', 'C'), (4, 'A', 'B'), (4, 'C', 'B')]
```

Answer (score 0):

So here it is my solution without the need of additional libraries:

```
dict
{'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [3, 4], 'C': [1, 4, 5]}

edges=[]

for index,item in enumerate(dict):
    for i in range(index+1,len(dict)):
        for x in dict[item]:
            for y in dict[dict.keys()[i]]:
                if x==y : edges.append((x,item,dict.keys()[i]))
print edges

[(1, 'A', 'C'), (4, 'A', 'C'), (3, 'A', 'B'), (4, 'A', 'B'), (4, 'C', 'B')]
```